# How does epigenetics affect the birth conditions via alcohol?

Tags: genetics, molecular-genetics, molecular-evolution

[Recent study](http://www.ajsc.us/files/ajsc0030217.pdf) has shown that epigenetics can play role in male-caused infertility and it cites for example studies which showed an enhancing of silent genes when drinking alcohol. Since the study argues this as a reason to the negative newborns' conditions, it has to act negatively on the organism somehow.

I would call an epigenetic influence on the fetuses an influence that is meant to prepare the fetus on the change in the conditions. Does the evolution of the enhanced genes any relate to the alcohol consumption, or is it just a negative coincidence?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. The "study" you mention is a review. Like pretty much it reviews, it proves nothing. In general we have very limited abilities to change the epigenome in controlled, experimental conditions - a requirement in order to prove anything. Also, I searched with Ctrl+F, in the paper you mentioned, "enhance", "silent", "infertility", and did not find any mention. Can you give an example of gene that you are thinking of?

Comment: I mean the conclusions from the chapter: Effects of environmental exposure on parental epigenetics: alcohol             Sorry I can't get to the original study.